# Differences between real numbers in $ACA_0 + \lnot Con(PA)$ and standard real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, soft-question, peano-axioms, reverse-math

Let $M = (\mathbb N_M, 0_M, +_M, \times_M, <_M, D_M)$ be a model of $ACA_0 + \lnot Con(PA)$. We define $\mathbb R_M$ as Dedekind cuts on $D_M$.

What can we say about the differences between $\mathbb R_M$ and $\mathbb R$? We know for example that B-W fails in $\mathbb Q_M$. I also suspect it to fail for $\mathbb R_M$ if we represent sequences of real numbers by function formulas $\phi(n,x)$, where $n$ is a natural number and $x$ is a set representing a real number.

What other differences are there?

Comment: Um what is $D_M$?

Comment: As long as ACAo holds, adding independent arithmetical sentences seems to have no effect on the topological structure of the reals, apart from the existence of particular reals witnessing the sentences.

Comment: @user21820 The subsets of $\mathbb N$ that the quantifiers quantify over. If $D_M = P(\mathbb N_M)$, it is a full model.

Comment: @PyRulez: Okay. In any case, ACA0 can form the Turing jump of any set in $D_M$, and so the reals under any reasonable encoding will behave like they satisfy definable completeness, namely that any upper-bounded sequence of reals has a supremum. That is the main reason that practical results in real analysis can be proven in ACA0.

Comment: Also, note that the computable reals satisfy the first-order theory of the reals, but fails to satisfy definable completeness because there is a computable upper-bounded sequence of computable reals that does not have a computable supremum (such a sequence can be easily constructed using the halting problem). However, once we close under Turing jumps then this problem vanishes. Specifically, the collection of reals that can each be computed from some finite Turing jump satisfies the first-order theory of reals and definable completeness. It is also countable.

Comment: @user21820: the set of reals that can be computed from some $\emptyset^n$ will have the property that every arithmetically definable Dedekind cut has a least upper bound, but there will be definable but non-arithmetical Dedekind cuts whose upper bounds are non-arithmetical reals, not computable from any $\emptyset^n$.

Comment: In particular, here's the example I had in mind. If we start with the $\omega$-model ARITH = $\{ Z : (\exists n) [Z \leq_T \text{TJ}^n(\emptyset)]\}$, we can define $\emptyset^\omega$ as the set $\{ (n,m) : (\exists X) [ X_0 = \emptyset \land (\forall p < n) [X_{p+1} = \text{TJ}(X_p)] \land m \in X_n]\}$. Then we can make a definable Dedekind cut for a real whose decimal expansion computes $\emptyset^\omega$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Wait by "definable completeness" in my comment I meant within ACA0, not within our meta-theory. Specifically, ACA0 proves the (suitably encoded) sentence that every upper-bounded sequence of reals has a supremum. In other words, every model of ACA0 is closed under supremum of upper-bounded sequences of reals. Now that it's more precise, what I'm saying is correct, right?

Comment: @user21820: the sequence I wrote above is $\Sigma^1_1$ definable over the model ARITH of ACAo.  If we only want to say "every sequence of reals with an upper bound has a least upper bound", then we don't need to talk about definable sequences.  What I was saying in my comment is that ACAo does not prove that every definable sequence of rationals with an upper bound has a least upper bound in the reals.

Comment: @CarlMummert: As I said, I meant (conservatively) definable within ACA0, not definable within ZFC or whatever meta-theory you are using. Clearly, ACA0 cannot prove something about a sequence it cannot even construct. I used the term "definable completeness" to distinguish it from full-semantics second-order completeness. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many examples about the topology of the reals in $ACA_0$ in Simpson's $\it Subsystems\ of\ Second$-$\it Order\ Arithmetic$. I don't think $Con(PA)$ itself has a usable topological interpretation, but since $ATR_0$, the next Big Five system above $ACA_0$, does prove $Con(PA)$, you could also look at the chapter on $ATR_0$; those theorems should be false in your system.

$ACA_0$ is strong enough to prove $\it most$ properties of the reals that you would find in an intro to real analysis. To use an example you mentioned already, the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is provable in $ACA_0$ (for the Dedekind cuts $\mathbb{R}_M$): For any sequence $\langle r_1,r_2,\ldots\rangle$ of cuts in $[0,1]$, you can zero in on an convergent subsequence by iteratively asking the arithmetical question, 'Are infinitely many $r_i$ in the sequence bigger than my chosen value $q$?'.

One well-known theorem that won't hold in your system are the Cantor-Bendixson Theorem (requires $\Pi^1_1$ comprehension); or the lesser-known, related Perfect Set Theorem for closed sets (requires $ATR_0$).